# Feedback on Undergraduate Level Proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am looking for feedback on my proof skills to get an idea of what I should work on. Hopefully my solution is valid, but I'd mainly like feedback on clarity/readability or any other criticisms [or compliments] you have.

For context, this problem is from an undergraduate level course on set theory (Kaplinsky's "Set theory and Metric Spaces").

Problem: Let {$A_{i}$} for i=1, 2, 3, .... be a countable infinity of infinite sets with infinite cardinal number d. Prove that $\bigcup_{i}A_{i}$ has the same cardinal number d

Proof:

$d\geqℵ_{0}$ as $ℵ_{0}$ is the lowest infinite cardinal, so true by Theorem 16

Therefore o($A_{1}ℵ_{0}) = o(A_{1}) = d$

$A_{0}$ and all other $A_{i}$ have the same cardinality, so a bijection exists from $A_{0}$ to $A_{i}$ for all i

Denote $f_{i}$ to be a bijection from $A_{1}$ to $A_{i}$ (eg $f_{3}$ bijects $A_{1}$ to $A_{3}$)

Consider the map g: $A_{i}ℵ_{0}$→$\bigcup_{i}A_{i}$ defined by (x, i)→$f_{i}(x)$

Any element $y \in \bigcup_{i}A_{i}$ must be in $A_{i}$ for some i

$f_{i}^{-1}(y)$ exists in $A_{1}$ as f is a bijection, so y is mapped to by ($f_{i}^{-1}(y)$, i))

So g is a surjection, implying $d \geq o(\bigcup_{i}A_{i}$)

An injection from $A_{1}$ to $\bigcup_{i}A_{i}$ exists (choose the identity map), implying $d\leq o(\bigcup_{i}A_{i})$

Therefore o($\bigcup_{i}A_{i}$) = d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct, so that is a great start! So let's have a look at some points for improvement.

**Formatting.** This may just be that you are still learning how to use MathJax on this site (or LaTeX in general), but that is an important skill anyway. Not every bit of math is typed in math mode (i.e. between `$ $`). For example, some of the $o(\ldots)$ and $d$ are not in math mode (e.g. the last line). Also, some symbols seem to be missing. For example, you write $o(A_1 \aleph_0)$, where you probably mean $o(A_1 \times \aleph_0)$.

**Notation.** I said your proof is correct, because I can understand what you mean to say and you mean to say the correct thing. However, your notation says something different. For example: you define $g$ as a map $A_i \times \aleph_0 \to \bigcup_i A_i$. The first $A_i$ is wrong here, this should be $A_1$, otherwise we could not apply $f_i$ to it. Also, two lines before that you talk about $A_0$ instead of $A_1$. Even though it then follows that there should also be a bijection $A_1 \to A_i$ for all $i$ (because of transitivity), this only makes things more confusing.

**Structure.** Once you constructed $g$ you want to show that $g$ is surjective to conclude $d \geq o(\bigcup_i A_i)$, but the reader only discovers this after they have read through your proof of that fact. It is usually better to announce what step you will prove next, so the reader knows what to expect. Example:

> Having constructed $g$, we will show that $d \geq o(\bigcup_i A_i)$ by showing that $g$ is surjective. So let $y \in \bigcup_i A_i$, then ...

Of course, if the next step would be only a one sentence step this is overkill. Deciding when this would be better is a matter of experience.

This probably gives you something to keep in mind when writing your next proof.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Yeah I am struggling with latex. On the note about g being a bijection, would I need to specify that I chose disjoint representations for each $A_{i}$? It was my intent when I constructed g, but I didn’t know how to say that disjoint representations can be chosen without being kinda wordy.

Comment: @Wessst For LaTeX: put entire formulas between the ```$ $``` (not just parts of it). Also, this might be helpful: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). There is also an entire StackExchange community for LaTeX, might be worth checking out!

Comment: To clarify,  I mean if a were an element of both $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ then $g^{-1}(a) = {(f_{1}^{-1}(a), 1), (f_{2}^{-1}(a), 2)}$, so it’s pre image is not unique

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll check it out

Comment: @Wessst You're right, I was thinking disjoint union. My bad, I'll correct that in my answer.